# Do I need to purchase additional licenses for external developers logging in periodically?

Tags: licenses

If I were to hire an external developer to customize my Salesforce org, how do they get access? Am I required to purchase an extra license just for them to do the initial setup, and make modifications every now and then?

Comment: You can purchase one extra license and assign it to your active developer.

Comment: Ask your account executive about a Limited Login License, which allows only a few logins per month. They're less costly than normal licenses, with the obvious limitation that they can't log in more than a few times a month.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Community/Portal users, then yes.

If you are talking about internal/platform users, then that's going to be tough. Actually, you're talking about a user who has to make configuration changes to your org, so that is, by definition, an internal user. You won't be able to buy a limited login internal license unless you have some serious spend with Salesforce.

I wish I had better news. You'll just have to deactivate another user while this contractor/consultant is working.